# Increase the number of workers in parallel pool with Matlab 2012b

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I tried in "Parallel"-->"Manage Cluster Profiles"-->"Edit", and then I put 16 in the box of "number of workers to start on your local machine".

As I execute

```
matlabpool open 16;
```

It fails in warning "NumWorkers must be an integer from 1 to 12." So is there any way to increase the limit? Or what is the cost to buy a license to implement this?

Comment: Refer to the duplicate.  `tl;dr`: if you want to increase the amount of workers, you must use R2014a or higher.  The limit is now 512.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you. I just got a version of R2014a. So does it come with the increased number, or do I have to pay to use the 512?

Comment: If you got R2014a, you've already "paid" for it.  If you're able to, I would try and upgrade to R2015b. Lots of optimizations and features have been introduced in the latest version of MATLAB.